# Understanding how list iteration works

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
myList = [1,2,3]
item = 2
if item in myList:
    print("yes")
```

Does `if item in myList: print("yes")` just like `for i in myList: if i == item: print("yes")`? If not, how does it work? I think the first method is faster. Can anyone explain?

Comment: Yes, they are equivalent. The `in` operator is faster because the iteration is done internally by the Python interpreter.

Answer (score -1):

The first one *implicitly* traverses the list, the second *explicitly*, that’s one difference. Another difference is that in case of `for`, it’ll continue iteration unless you put a `break`.

Answer (score -1):

The first method is faster as it is done in native C code in Python despite requiring traversal of the list with up to n comparisons for an n length list.  The second one is not the same output but it would be the same if you change to:

```
for i in myList:
  if i == item: print("yes"); break
```

Otherwise your code would print "yes" for as many times as matching items are found in the list.

Ideally in queries on lists are to be avoided as well.  Generally sets or dictionaries are the way to go as you get O(1) in queries for both sets and keys of dictionaries especially important when the number of items will be arbitrarily sized.